# Functionalities to develop in Sitecore page

Tags: content-search

We are in the starting stage of the project. The requirement is to develop the different functionalities in parallel. Few of the basic modules are

- Login
- Search
- View details etc.

Now the problem is, client is not finalized the requirement on the Login, so they want us to start with the **Search** functionalities. As per the design, during login, profile will be set in the sitecore(using profile provider) and some of the profile values needs to be used in the **Search** functionality. As customer asked us to start with Search, these profiles will not  be available in the sitecore.

We are having hard time thinking how we will be able to implement this. 
Also, customer wants have that functionality before implementing the Login.

Can anyone please en-light us on the approach that we have to taken.

If we cannot deliver in that way we can go back and tell them. For that i need some strong points.

Comment: you can create a dummy AuthenticationProvider and call it behind the AuthenticationManager. Basic Profile will be created. Or for time being, you can use Sitecore as AuthenticationProvider. Just don't set `Sitecore Client Users` role to them. This prevents them from logging to Sitecore client. This way you can continue with your search implementation. As @Sandbeck mentioned abstraction is the key.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement strict OO design principles in order to isolate the different problems. If you create the necessary “hooks”, you can later expand on the functionality.

First, you know you need something like a **BaseUserSearchProfile** that can be feed to your search implementation, even though you don’t know the exact content you can still model this behavior.

Secondly, you could create an “Anonymous” user in Sitecore, that you automatically log in via your own login pipeline, when a user visits – you extent the user with the **BaseUserSearchProfile** to emulate the final setup.

This means, that your code is ready to be expanded with profiles when you know what to react to – and the known search features can be implemented - it would be the same for all visitors, until login page is developed.